# My on/off switch doesn't go off and i don't know how to fix

Tags: javascript, function, clearinterval

I need a button that will show and update the time each second since clicked. If it's clicked again it's supposed to show nothing. I tried so much (switch etc.) but i can't solve it. If i click on the button it shows the time and updates it but if i click it again it emptys the innerHTML of the paragraph but a second later the time pops up again and updates itself.
Can someone tell me please why does my clearInterval does not work and how i can fix this?

```js
var abc = false;

function switched() {
 let x = document.getElementById("switch");

 if (!abc) { 
  var myFun = setInterval(Time, 1000);
  abc = true;
  return;
 }

 if (abc) {
  clearInterval(myFun);
  abc = false;
  x.innerHTML = "";
  return;
 }

 function Time() {
  var date1 = new Date();
  var t = date1.toLocaleTimeString();
  x.innerHTML = t;
 }
}
```

```html
<p>On switch which shows you're current time:</p>
<button onclick="switched()">On</button>
<p id="switch"></p>
```

Comment: Don't use 1998 `onclick="switched()"`, get your button on the JS side, e.g using document.querySelector, and then add an event listener with a normal event handler binding (e.g. `btn.addEventListner("click", evt => toggle())`). Also, functions use lowerCamelCase, only classes use UpperCamelCase. And on that note, if you're setting text, don't use `innerHTML`, use `x.textContent = ...`. And finally: good indentation gets you more eyes, always worth auto-formatting your code when putting it in a post.

Comment: The issue is that the `myFun` is scoped too low.  It only exists for the duration of the method call.  You need to elevate it's scope to the same level as the `abc`

Comment: It'd really help if you used descriptive names for your variables, instead of `abc`, `x`, `t`, ...

Comment: Welcome!
I've modified your code in my answer and provided some pointers and explanation.
Use what you know first, and "advance" at your own pace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the variable holding the interval globally.
Also, the button and the paragraph.
Instead of `abc`, use the value of the button's textContent.
Call Time right-away to immediately show the time, and then every 1000ms.
Name variables and ids more meaningfully.
Avoid declaring a variable for one-time use.
Describe clearly to the user what is going on and possible actions and results.
Using `onclick` is perfectly fine.  I just recently started using `let` instead of `var`, and I guess that here I actually should have used `const` (I didn't, for debugging), and also, I recently started using `textContent` instead of `innerText` = I'm learning too!
(Minor grammatical error: "your", not "you're")

---

Addendum: Ok, `let` for `interval` because it's assigned a value later on (and, most likely, multiple times), and `const` for the `button` and `paragraph` because they will always "point" to the same thing and only that "thing"'s properties will change...

```js
let interval;
const button = document.getElementById("switchButton");
const paragraph = document.getElementById("timeParagraph");

function toggleSwitch() {
  if(button.textContent == "On") {
    button.textContent = "Off";
    Time();
    interval = setInterval(Time, 1000);
  }
  else {
    button.textContent = "On";
    clearInterval(interval);
    paragraph.textContent = "";
  }
}

function Time() {
  paragraph.textContent = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

```html
<p>Turn On to show your current time, Off to clear:</p>
<button id="switchButton" onclick="toggleSwitch()">On</button>
<p id="timeParagraph"></p>
```